# Convert Every Other Row into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
time                tagid   stringvalue
2/9/2019 19:06:09   500     20945030
2/9/2019 17:54:13   500 
2/9/2019 16:02:26   500     20946065
2/9/2019 16:02:00   500 
2/9/2019 16:01:07   500     20936368
2/9/2019 15:29:13   500 
2/9/2019 14:58:15   500     20934130
2/9/2019 14:57:58   500 
2/9/2019 13:20:40   500     20934131
```

I would like to convert it in SQL to look like this:

```
EndTime             tagid   stringvalue StartTime           tagid   stringvalue
2/9/2019 14:58:15   500     20934130    2/9/2019 14:57:58   500     20934130
2/9/2019 16:01:07   500     20936368    2/9/2019 15:29:13   500     20936368
2/9/2019 16:02:26   500     20946065    2/9/2019 16:02:00   500     20946065
2/9/2019 19:06:09   500     20945030    2/9/2019 17:54:13   500     20945030
```

Basically, I need to move every other row to additional columns.
How would you do this?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your actual data is as well behaved as what you showed us, and every start record has a matching end record, then we might be able to get away with just using `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT time, tagid, stringvalue,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY time) - 1 AS rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    MAX(time) AS EndTime,
    MAX(tagid) AS tagid,
    MAX(stringvalue) AS stringvalue,
    MIN(time) AS StartTime,
    MAX(tagid) AS tagid,
    MAX(stringvalue) AS stringvalue
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    rn / 2;
```

Comment: Actually last row doesnt have a match. But still think is a good solution. https://rextester.com/TNXO74681

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution would be just to `LAG` the time to make the `StartTime` for  given `EndTime`, and then remove rows with no `stringvalue` (the rows with the `StartTime` value):

```
SELECT EndTime,
       tagid,
       stringvalue,
       StartTime,
       tagId,
       stringvalue
FROM (SELECT time AS EndTime, tagid, stringvalue,
             LAG(time) OVER(ORDER BY tagid, time) AS StartTime
      FROM tags) t
WHERE stringvalue IS NOT NULL
```

Output:

```
EndTime                 tagid   stringvalue     StartTime               tagId   stringvalue
09/02/2019 13:20:40     500     20934131                                500     20934131
09/02/2019 14:58:15     500     20934130        09/02/2019 14:57:58     500     20934130
09/02/2019 16:01:07     500     20936368        09/02/2019 15:29:13     500     20936368
09/02/2019 16:02:26     500     20946065        09/02/2019 16:02:00     500     20946065
09/02/2019 19:06:09     500     20945030        09/02/2019 17:54:13     500     20945030
```

If you don't want the row where `StartTime` is not set, just add

```
AND StartTime IS NOT NULL
```

to the `WHERE` clause.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=f7dc6d1b94fae3abff07e299b20df2bb)

Answer (score 0):

I might be tempted to do this:

```
with t as (
      select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by (case when stringvalue is null then 1 else 0 end)
                                order by time
                               ) as seqnum
      from <your table name here> t
     )
select t1.*, t2.*
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum;
```

Comment: I recievd this error when I tried it: Msg 252, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Recursive common table expression 't' does not contain a top-level UNION ALL operator.

Comment: @SamSmith1986 . . . The inner `t` is for your table name, which is not specified in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Dateadd (s,t_stamp/1000, '1969/12/31 20:00:00') AS TimeStamp,a.tagid,a.stringvalue
From sqlt_data_5_2019_02 a 
join      sqlth_te b
ON        b.id =    a.tagid
where     tagpath in ('LL543')

WITH cte AS (
            SELECT Dateadd (s,t_stamp/1000, '1969/12/31 20:00:00') AS TimeStamp,a.tagid, a.stringvalue,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t_stamp) - 1 AS rn
            FROM sqlt_data_5_2019_02 a 
            JOIN  sqlth_te b
            ON   b.id = a.tagid
            where     tagpath in ('LL543')
            )
SELECT
    MIN(TimeStamp) AS StartTime,
    MAX(TimeStamp) AS EndTime,
    MAX(tagid) AS tagid,
    MAX(stringvalue) AS stringvalue,
    MAX(tagid) AS tagid,
    MAX(stringvalue) AS stringvalue
FROM cte
GROUP BY  rn / 2;
```